# Freq. Response of Discrete System

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let's say that I have the following continuous system:

$$G(s)= \frac{2}{1+s}$$

I could convert it to a discrete system using for example the Tustin approximation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_transform

So I replace s with:

$$s \rightarrow{}  \frac{2(1-z^{-1})}{T_e(1+z^{-1})} $$

Hence I get the approx. discrete transfer function:

$$G(z)= \frac{2}{1+\frac{2(1-z^{-1})}{T_e(1+z^{-1})}}$$

Now my question is, **how can I compute its frequency response ?**

In the end, I would like to be able to compare the discrete approx. freqe. response with the  freq. response of the continuous original transfer function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given

$$
\left|H(j\omega)\right| = \left|G(j\omega)\right|=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\omega^2+1}}
$$

from $G'(z)$ we can obtain $G'(j\omega)$ by considering the transformation associated to the sampling phenomena

$$
z = e^{-j\omega T}
$$

hence

$$
G'(z) = \frac{2 T (z+1)}{(T+2) z+T-2}\to G'(j\omega) = \frac{2 T \left(1+e^{i \omega  T}\right)}{(T+2) e^{i \omega  T}+T-2}
$$

and

$$
\left| H'(j\omega)\right| = \sqrt{\frac{4 T^2 (\cos (\omega  T)+1)}{\left(T^2-4\right) \cos (\omega  T)+T^2+4}}
$$

Attached the comparison between $|H'|$ (red) and $|H|$ (blue) for $T = 1$

[image]

and also $\angle{H}$,$\angle{H'}$

[image]

Comment: Wow ! Thank you very much ! Your answer is perfect !! One can clearly see the approximation as the red and the blue curve do not completely overlap for the magnitude plot. I know that one can replace z with $z = e^{-j\omega T}$ but I have never quiet understood why... Do you know why?

Comment: Nicely illustrated. +1